# Initializing an array of integers in C, what does it look like in RAM under x86?

Tags: c, sockets, constants, ipv6, endianness

```
u_int32_t ip6_address[1][4] = { {0x00000001, 0x0, 0x0, 0x12345678} };
```

1. How would the above look in a RAM hex-dump byte-by-byte when running on an x86 PC CPU?

Comment: Yes, little-endian x86 is in the description.

Comment: Did you try looking at it in a debugger?  Or even just in the object file?

Comment: What's stopping you from printing out the contents of your memory?

Comment: I don't understand why you wouldn't just look - regardless, if you read the documentation for your machine you can easily reconstruct it by hand, yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes it's easiest to just look:

```
$ cat example.c 
#include <stdint.h>
uint32_t ip6_address[1][4] = { {0x00000001, 0x0, 0x0, 0x12345678} };
$ make example.o
clang -Wall -Wextra -pedantic   -c -o example.o example.c
$ otool -d example.o 
example.o:
(__DATA,__data) section
0000000000000000    01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 78 56 34 12
```

You can do something analogous for your second example.

Comment: OK, so follow the same steps as in my example.  Define one, compile it, and dump the object file.  Done.  Network byte order is big endian if you want to do it by hand.

Comment: If you don't have Linux immediately available, why do you care?  You couldn't do anything useful with the information anyway.  Why not just wait until the next time you *do* have a machine available, figure out the answer and then do whatever you want to based on the results?

Comment: I would assume that the IPv6 address would look like `00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 12 34 56 78`.

Answer (score 1):

You can dump any memory area by inspecting it with a `unsigned char *`

```
void dump(void *address, size_t bytes) {
    unsigned char *p = address;
    while (bytes--) printf("%02X ", *p++);
    puts("");
}
```

Comment: Or I can use a debugger. But that's beside the point of this question.